# Questions about loyalty rewards for playing previous borderlands?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

How do i get loyalty reward? Do i need to have both savegame or i just need 1 savegame to get loyalty reward? Right now i just has borderlands 1 savegame
Is there any different reward from BL 1 or 2 save game ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewards depend on what kind and how many previous games you have.

If you have a borderlands 1 savestate, you get a special weapon and a special skin, also a bunch of moonstones.
With a borderlands 2 savestate, you can be happy about a special weapon, another special skin, a few moonstones and badass points.
When you got both, you get everything, plus even more moonstones.

Comment: Does the save state need to be from a particular part of the game? Like "you need to have finished the game"? or could you even have a save state where you just entered claptrap's cave in BL2?

Comment: Thanks for amswering my question. I just found my BL 2 savegame. And i just about to copy to my documents so BL Pre Sequel can detect. But its possible to get bonus if i played the game almost half the story? Or d i need to do new game?
And sorry for my english :)